# Why is semicolon required for this statement?

Tags: javascript

The following code returns an error that says 
"console.log(...) is not a function"

```
if (4<5) console.log('hi') 
(4<5) ? console.log('hi') : console.log('bye')
```

The following code does not return any error

```
if (4<5) console.log('hi')
if (4<5) console.log('hi')
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Ternary operator cannot be left alone with the truthy part. There is no wonder in that, this is the syntax.

Comment: My bad, just updated the question.

Comment: I don't get that error message with your updated code

Comment: There is no `}` token in your question. Please provide more context.

Comment: Provide space between if and ternary condition

Comment: Now your question title doesn't make sense....

Comment: Because you have declare condition one by one and if condition looks for { syntex you don't have provide one line space between them

Comment: @Liam: It does (the question could be clearer), because if you add a semicolon at the end of the first line, the code does what the OP expects it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a semicolon at the end of the first line, the code tries to use return value of the first `console.log` as a function and call it with the argument `4<5`; this is clearer if you remove the line break:

```
if (4<5) console.log('hi')(4<5) ? console.log('hi') : console.log('bye')
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- looks like calling `console.log` and then
//                                  using the result as a function
```

There's the potential for this any time you combine leaving off semicolons (which means you're relying on an *error-correction mechanism*<sup>1</sup>) with expression statements. Since expression statements are, by their nature, expressions, if the parser can use them in the previous expression or statement, it will.

---

FWIW, [astexplorer.net](http://astexplorer.net/) is a cool tool I've recently found (thanks to the Babel project). It's an interactive syntax tree explorer which can use any of several parsers to parse your code and tell you exactly *how* it was parsed. And from the github account, it was started by our own [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Quoting Brendan Eich](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/):

> ASI is (formally speaking) a syntactic error correction procedure. If you start to code as if it were a universal significant-newline rule, you will get into trouble.

Comment: But TJ, If that is the case, undefined is not a function must be the apt error. Isn't it? Because `console.log()` would return undefined.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: That's what the error I quoted in my answer is saying: The result of `console.log(...)` is not a function. (It's not saying `console.log` is not a function.)